Merge vitest and playwright coverage repors
I run vitest coverage via:
$ VITE_COVERAGE=true vitest --ui --coverage.enabled=true

and I get a really cool interface with all my vitest tests and coverage.
Now, I'd like to keep using this interface, but also add the coverage gathered by playwright, that I run with:
# generate the tests
$ VITE_COVERAGE=true npx playwright test
# generate the report in ./coverage/index.html
$ npx nyc report --report-dir ./coverage --temp-dir .nyc_output --reporter=html --exclude-after-remap false

How could I do that?
